# Permissions required for row counts to show up on Object Explorer Details

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions, ssms

I'm having a weird security issue.  I have a user that's using SSMS 18.2 on a SQL 2016 server.  They are a member of db_datareader but when they pull up the the *Row Count* column in Object Explorer Details it's blank. As best I can tell it is requiring DBO in order to get the row counts to show up.

User with read access:
[image]

User with dbo access:
[image]

Is this a bug or intentional? Does anyone know if there is a lower level of permissions that will give this row count? I know there are plenty of other ways to get the row count, *sys.partitions* for example, however the user insists they want to use the OED window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Through a little experimentation, I discovered that rowcount requires "VIEW DATABASE STATE".

Methodology: Captured queries that SSMS runs and executed as a user with datareader permissions only. One in particular throws an error. After granting the permission, verified that rowcounts were now visible.

Comment: Specifically the query that throws the error is one accessing `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` to return `IndexSpaceUsed` - the one getting the row count from `sys.partitions` actually works fine